# Reverse order of factors in an element of a braid group.

Tags: group-theory

A braid group $Br_n$ is a group given by the presentation: 
$$
Br_n=\langle \sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_n: \sigma_i \sigma_j = \sigma_j \sigma_i, |i-j|>1, \sigma_i \sigma_j \sigma_i = \sigma_j \sigma_i \sigma_j, |i-j|=1 \rangle. 
$$
Suppose that $A = \sigma_{i_1} \cdots \sigma_{i_m}$, $B = \sigma_{i_1'} \cdots \sigma_{i_{m'}'}$ and $A=B$ in $Br_n$. Let $A^{op} = \sigma_{i_m} \cdots \sigma_{i_1}$ and $B^{op} = \sigma_{i_{m'}'} \cdots \sigma_{i_1'}$. Do we have $A^{op} = B^{op}$ in $Br_n$? Thank you very much.

Comment: I think so. The words that you are considering all lie in the monoid defined by the presentation. It is known that two words in the monoid are equal in the group if anf only if they are equal in the monoid. So $A=B$ in the monoid, which  implies that you can transform $A$ to $B$ by using substitutions arising from the defining relations. Since these are all palindromic, you could apply the same operations to $A^{\rm op}$ to transform it to $B^{\rm op}$.